# Visual Similarity Algorithms (for CBIR)

Tags: search, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition, cbir

I am trying to build a collection of Visual similarity between images, being size, angle, color, rotation invariant for Content Based Image Retrieval.Quite agnostic about the platform but .NET, Java or Python are preferred. But if others are available, pls. suggest away.

I am quite familiar with OpenCV Match template and Match shapes. I have also looked at AForge.NET.

p.s. Something similar to http://www.imgseek.net/home would be ideal:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content Based Image Retrieval is a field of heavy research. Unfortunately it is not my field of research, therefore I am unable to give you an authoritative suggestion on a viable algorithm. But I can give you the website where I would start looking for an answer:
[CVPapers - Computer Vision Resource](http://www.cvpapers.com) (check out the Computer Vision Paper Indexes)

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for. But useful link. Thanks.